# Restrict view of table between certain times by using sysdate statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

I need to restrict a view on a table between certain times to a certain user. I can't find any information about how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [Virtual Private Database (VPD)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm) policy to enforce this, or more simply grant users access to a view instead of the table where the view is something like:

```
create view data_vw as
select * from data
where (to_char(sysdate,'HH24MI') between '0800' and '1730'
      or user = 'CERTAINUSER'
      );
```

In either case the users will still have access but the table/view will return no rows sometimes.

Comment: I think this should be `user <> 'CERTAINUSER' or ( sysdate_thing and user = 'CERTAINUSER' )`

Comment: @Ben: maybe, maybe not.  I interpreted "need to restrict a view of a table between certain times to a certain user" as meaning: "between certain times, only a certain user can see the table; at other times everyone can".  However, a different interpretation could be what the OP meant.

Comment: Using VPD allows significantly more flexibility in the solution, because you're invoking PL/SQL to add a where clause to all SQL against the base table.

Answer (score 1):

How's about something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SOME_VIEW AS
  SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD_ETC
    FROM REAL_TABLE
    WHERE USER = 'MY_BUDDY' AND
          TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH')) BETWEEEN 8 AND 16
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL AS FIELD1, NULL AS FIELD2, NULL AS FIELD_ETC
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE USER <> 'MY_BUDDY' OR
          TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24')) NOT BETWEEEN 8 AND 16;
```

This would allow user MY_BUDDY to see the data from REAL_TABLE between 08:00 and 16:59 each day.

Share and enjoy.